# Group emailing with custom greeting

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

I have to email 50 people about a date change for an event. Normally I'd just BCC them but the request this time is that I make the emails more personalized and have them begin with "Hello *First Name*,". Anyone know a good automated way to go about this? Thunderbird plugin? I have a CSV file with the correct column titles that I can import into a mail client and get all the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Word's built in mail merge feature to create a personalized email.  From the "Mailings" ribbon, select to start a "Email message" mail merge.  Use your csv file to select the recipients or just select them from your Address Book, and write your email with the mail merge fields where needed.  Then complete your merge to send send the emails.

You can also access this functionality directly from Outlook.  The [Outlook Team Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20101108032421/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/outlook/archive/2008/09/23/mail-merge-how-to-send-a-personalized-e-mail-to-many-people-at-once.aspx) has a nice tutorial on how to do the same thing from within Outlook.

Comment: This answer is great and led me to exactly what I need, though "mail merge" seems a terribly non intuitive name for it. Thunderbird plugin for mail merge: https://addons.mozilla.org/af/thunderbird/addon/47144/ .